# Can I use view to filter by fields in referenced node?

Tags: views, nodes

I have 2 node types: Project and Designer.
I have a third node type Contribute with a body that explain the contribute and a field node reference with maximum 2 values that "links" the designer to the project that he contribute.
I can reuse Contribute to link 2 Projects, or 2 Designers, but I can't do this:

In the Designer page I want 2 blocks: one containing the Contribute nodes that link that designer with some Project; one containing the Contribute nodes that link that designer to other Designer s.

With Views I can only create one single block listing all Contribute nodes that links the current node (from URL) to another node, I want to filter from the type or the tags of the nodes referenced in the field.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try add relationship on refrenced nodes and then add filter from this reference?

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at adding Relationship(s) to your View.

You also likely want to look at [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view):

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.
>
> This view handler can accept arguments from fields of the parent view
>   using tokens and pass them into the child view for each row. Raw or
>   rendered token values can be used, as well as static values.

Or [Views Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield):

> Viewfield provides a field that holds a reference to a View and
>   renders it whenever the entity containing the field is displayed.
>
> Features
>
> - Author chooses a view and display from a list.
> - View arguments are supplied through tokens.
> - Administrators may restrict which views may be assigned.
> - Administrators may supply a common value that will be used for all entities in a content type.

Using either of these modules you can figure out your relationships for the views you want and for instance using ViewsField you can add a View to the Designer Content Type with 2 new Views: Contributed Project Nodes views, and a Similiar or Linked Designers View. You can pass the Designers `uid` as a token to filter these views.